# How do I write a function below the main?

Tags: c++, declaration, function-prototypes

I have a teacher/professor that only like writing functions below the main and not above it. How would I rewrite this in order to write the functions below main. Always been taught how to do it below, would I just declare it beforehand? How would it look like if so?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
/* Output
Enter 4 test score numbers
80 90 80 90
Average is 86.6667

Enter 4 test score numbers
70 80 -60 90
Bad Data

*/
bool input(double& test1, double& test2, double& test3, double& test4)
{
cout << "Enter 4 test score numbers" << endl;
cin >> test1;
cin >> test2;
cin >> test3;
cin >> test4;

if(test1 < 0 || test2 < 0 || test3 < 0 || test4 < 0)
return false;
else
return true;
}

double average(double test1, double test2, double test3, double test4, bool data)
{
if(data == false)
{
cout << "Bad Data" << endl;
return -1;
}
double low = test1;
if(test2 < low)
{
low = test2;
}
if(test3 < low)
{
low = test3;
}
if(test4 < low)
{
low = test4;
}
return (test1+test2+test3+test4-low)/3;
}

int main()
{
double test1, test2, test3, test4;
bool data;
data = input(test1, test2, test3, test4);
double avg = average(test1, test2, test3, test4, data);
if(avg != -1)
{
cout << "Average is " << avg << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried what you suggested trying? BTW: Your teacher's opinion is not generally shared. As new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Further, you could have reduced your code to a [mcve] and, if you want people to read it, indented it properly.

Comment: Yeah, just declare it before `main` with a function prototype.

Comment: Forward declaration before `main`, implementation after, should do the trick. But *why*?

Answer (score 7):

Just put the declarations before `main`:

```
bool input(double& test1, double& test2, double& test3, double& test4);
double average(double test1, double test2, double test3, double test4, bool data);
```

and the definitions after `main`:

```
bool input(double& test1, double& test2, double& test3, double& test4)
{
    ....
}

double average(double test1, double test2, double test3, double test4, bool data)
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is provide a function declaration above `main`.

`bool input(double test1, double test2, double test3, double test4);`

And then you can implement the function below `main`.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare function above main and implementation of function after the main function.

Answer (score 0):

**BEFORE** (*only function implementation*)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int sum(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}

int main(){
    cout<<sum(3, 5);
}
```

**AFTER** (*function declaration over main, function implementation under main*)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int sum(int a, int b);

int main(){
    cout<<sum(3, 5);
}

int sum(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just cut and paste your main() function on the top. And declare your functions using function prototypes.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
/* Output
Enter 4 test score numbers
80 90 80 90
Average is 86.6667

Enter 4 test score numbers
70 80 -60 90
Bad Data

*/

bool input(double& test1, double& test2, double& test3, double& test4);
double average(double test1, double test2, double test3, double test4, bool data);


int main()
{
double test1, test2, test3, test4;
bool data;
data = input(test1, test2, test3, test4);
double avg = average(test1, test2, test3, test4, data);
if(avg != -1)
{
cout << "Average is " << avg << endl;
}
return 0;
}


bool input(double& test1, double& test2, double& test3, double& test4)
{
cout << "Enter 4 test score numbers" << endl;
cin >> test1;
cin >> test2;
cin >> test3;
cin >> test4;

if(test1 < 0 || test2 < 0 || test3 < 0 || test4 < 0)
return false;
else
return true;
}

double average(double test1, double test2, double test3, double test4, bool data)
{
if(data == false)
{
cout << "Bad Data" << endl;
return -1;
}
double low = test1;
if(test2 < low)
{
low = test2;
}
if(test3 < low)
{
low = test3;
}
if(test4 < low)
{
low = test4;
}
return (test1+test2+test3+test4-low)/3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `prototypes` or `function declarations` above `main()`. A `declaration` or `prototype` specifies a unique name which includes information about its type. You also do not have to have an argument name in your `prototype` or `function declaration`. However, you do have to define it in the `definition`. Then you can put your functions below `main()`

For example, (using your example):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
double average(double, double, double, double, bool); //Prototype or function 
bool input(double&, double&, double&, double&); //Prototype or function declaration.
int main()
{
  //code.
}

double average(double test1, double test2, double test3, double test4, bool data)
{
 //code.
}
bool input(double& test1, double& test2, double& test3, double& test4)
{
 //code.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would create a header file with the function headers, include it in the top of the document, and then you can put it in from there.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "myheaders.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
double test1, test2, test3, test4;
bool data;
data = input(test1, test2, test3, test4);
double avg = average(test1, test2, test3, test4, data);
if(avg != -1)
{
cout << "Average is " << avg << endl;
}
return 0;
}


bool input(double& test1, double& test2, double& test3, double& test4)
{
cout << "Enter 4 test score numbers" << endl;
cin >> test1;
cin >> test2;
cin >> test3;
cin >> test4;

if(test1 < 0 || test2 < 0 || test3 < 0 || test4 < 0)
return false;
else
return true;
}

double average(double test1, double test2, double test3, double test4, bool data)
{
if(data == false)
{
cout << "Bad Data" << endl;
return -1;
}
double low = test1;
if(test2 < low)
{
low = test2;
}
if(test3 < low)
{
low = test3;
}
if(test4 < low)
{
low = test4;
}
return (test1+test2+test3+test4-low)/3;
}
```

In myheaders.h

```
bool input(double& test1, double& test2, double& test3, double& test4);
double average(double test1, double test2, double test3, double test4, bool data);
```

To be honest, it doesn't make sense to have those functions in the main. They should be separated.

You could just declare the function above the main as well, and technically you aren't having the function implemented above main, but that's kind of silly to do.

https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/header-files/